# Conditionally enable or disable modules in root main.tf terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, terraform, hcl

How do we select or disable modules in root main.tf

Example:

```
module "foo" {
  source = "bar"
  count   = "${var.include_module ? 1 : 0}"
```

}

Above one does not work, as per terraform issue discussion [link](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/953)

Any alternate method ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What version of Terraform are you using? `count` and `for_each` for modules were introduced in Terraform version [0.13.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/releases/tag/v0.13.0).

Note that the interpolation syntax you're using is deprecated. Use:

```
count = var.include_module ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: I was using 0.12, changed terraform binary and working